# Trying to understand spin in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, observables

I'm trying to understand the concept of spin in Quantum Mechanics. I'm reading "Road to Reality" by Penrose, which despite not being a textbook, is reputed to give one a deep insight into physical processes.

1. Let us suppose that we have a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle. It has two eigenstates- $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$. I would assume that spin $S$ is an operator such that when it acts on the wavefunction $\alpha |\uparrow\rangle+\beta|\downarrow\rangle$, it collapses it to one eigenstate, with an eigenvalue which would be the spin (so $\frac{1}{2}$ here). However, Penrose says that the spin can be thought of as the point $[\alpha:\beta]$ in $\Bbb{C}P^1$.

Why is this? Why do we not have a collapse to an eigenstate?

2. Let us suppose that we have a particle with spin $j$. Then $N=2j$. An angular momentum eigenstate of such a particle can be written as $\psi_{AB\dots N}$. I know that there are $N+1$ independent eigenstates, and that for even values of $N$, the eigenstates are spherical harmonic functions while for odd values of $N$ the eigenstates are spin-weighted spherical harmonic functions.

But how do you calculate the spin of this particle? One might say that the spin is just $j$. However, from the example of spin $\frac{1}{2}$, I would figure that the spin is suppose to be an element of a projective space. Is this not true?

Comment: Why do you think the spin operator should collapse the wavefunction? Does the energy operator collapse the state $(|1\rangle+|2\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ of the 1D infinite square well?

Comment: @G.Smith- All other observables that I've come across, like momentum, position, etc, collapse the wavefunction to one eigenstate, and the corresponding eigenvalue is the momentum, position, respectively. I would expect that the energy operator (which I'm assuming is differentiation with respect to time) does the same?

Comment: No, you have a very serious misunderstanding. None of these operators collapse a superposition of their eigenstates. For example, if you have two energy eigenstates, $\hat{H}\Psi_1=E_1\Psi_1$ and $\hat{H}\Psi_2=E_2\Psi_2$, then $\hat{H}(\Psi_1+\Psi_2)=E _1\Psi_1+E_2\Psi_2$. This is just simple linearity. You are confusing what an *operator* does to a superposition with what *measurement* does to a superposition.

Comment: @G.Smith- I see. Thanks for clarifying the difference between the action of an operator and the process of measurement (which I guess does collapse the wavefunction to an eigenstate). However, say we take the momentum operator $P_x=ih\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Does this not collapse the wavefunction to an eigenstate? Is the action of this operator on the wavefunction not the same as the measurement of momentum?

Comment: No, it is not. If you have two momentum eigenstates, $\hat{P}_x\Psi_1=p_{x1}\Psi_1$ and $\hat{P}_x\Psi_2=p_{x2}\Psi_2$, then $\hat{P}_x(\Psi_1+\Psi_2)=p_{x1}\Psi_1+p_{x2}\Psi_2$. No collapse from applying a linear operator!

Comment: @G.Smith- Thanks for the clarification. Could you also comment on my second question? I'll have to re-understand some basics of quantum mechanics I suppose

Comment: I don’t know what $\psi_{AB...N}$ is. I am used to writing spin states for spin $s$ as $|s\,m_s\rangle$. They satisy $\hat{\mathbf{S}}^2|s\,m_s\rangle=s(s+1)|s\,m_s\rangle$ and $\hat{\mathbf{S}}_z|s\,m_s\rangle=m_s|s\,m_s\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the measurement of an operator $\hat{\cal O}$ - which collapses the wave function to one of the eigenstates of $\hat{\cal O}$ - with a state, which can be a general linear combination of eigenstates of $\hat{\cal O}$.

In the case of spin (or more generally angular momentum) we speak of spin-$s$ when the largest possible eigenvalue is $\hbar s$.  Thus a spin-1 particle can have eigenvalue $\pm \hbar$ or $0\hbar$.

Note that the *direction* of the angular quantization axis is irrelevant since any direction is equally good as any other.  Thus, the possible eigenvalues of spin along $\hat x$, i.e. the eigenvalues of $\hat S_x$ are the same the eigenvalues of $\hat S_z$.  This does NOT mean the eigenstates are the same: just the *eigenvalues* are the same.  You can verify for yourself that the linear combinations 
$$
\vert\psi_\pm\rangle=\vert \uparrow \rangle \pm \vert \downarrow\rangle
$$
of eigenstates of $\hat S_z$ are actually eigenstates of $\hat S_y$.

A general spin-1/2 state will be a linear combination
$$
\vert \psi\rangle =\alpha \vert \uparrow\rangle+\beta\vert\downarrow\rangle.
$$
can be represented as a point on $\mathbb{CP}$ as in [the Bloch sphere.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere)